# Using NSProcessInfo from C++

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, foundation

Is it possible to use [[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion]](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsprocessinfo/1410906-operatingsystemversion?language=objc) from C++ or C and how do I do that?

Answer (score 7):

In XCode and Objective-C, files with extension `.mm` are treated as "mixed" in the sense that one single file can contain C++/C notion as well as Objective-C code, and that even C++/C function implementations can access Objective-C classes and send messages to them.

Such a `.mm`-files can then provide a trampoline function, i.e. a C-style function that is exposed and can then be used in pure C++/C-files (extension `.cpp`, where Objective-C code must not occur).

Let's consider the following setting:

1. A mixed file `ProcessInfoProvider.mm`, which calls `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion]` and provides the result in a C-style function `std::string getProcessInfoVersion_C()`,
2. A Pure cpp-file and a corresponding hpp-file `UseProcessInfoInC.cpp/hpp` defining a class `MyCppProcessInfo`, which provides a `printVersion()`-member function and which uses `getProcessInfoVersion_C`,
3. Some other file that instantiates `MyCppProcessInfo` and calls member function `printVersion()`

Let's start with `ProcessInfoProvider.mm`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Foundation/NSProcessInfo.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

std::string getProcessInfoVersion_C (void) {
    NSProcessInfo *processInfo = [[NSProcessInfo alloc] init];

    // check avaiability of the property operatingSystemVersion (10.10+) at runtime
    if ([processInfo respondsToSelector:@selector(operatingSystemVersion)])
    {
        NSOperatingSystemVersion versionObj = [processInfo operatingSystemVersion];

        char version[500];
        snprintf(version, 500, "Version %ld.%ld.%ld",
                 (long)versionObj.majorVersion,
                 (long)versionObj.minorVersion,
                 (long)versionObj.patchVersion);

        return version;
    }
    else
    {
        // Implement fallback for OSX 10.9 and below
        return "?";
    }
}
```

Note that `getProcessInfoVersion_C` is a C-style function but contains objective-C code in it's implementation.

Then, pure C++ files `UseProcessInfoInC.cpp/hpp` implement class `MyCppProcessInfo`:

```
// UseProcessInfoInC.hpp:
#ifndef UseProcessInfoInC_hpp
#define UseProcessInfoInC_hpp

class MyCppProcessInfo {
public:
    void printVersion(void);
};

#endif /* UseProcessInfoInC_hpp */
```

and

```
// UseProcessInfoInC.cpp:
#include "UseProcessInfoInC.hpp"
#include <iostream>

extern std::string getProcessInfoVersion_C (void);

void MyCppProcessInfo::printVersion(void)
{
    std::string version = getProcessInfoVersion_C();

    std::cout << version;
}
```

Note that these two files do not contain any Objective-C-stuff. 
Finally, let's try out `MyCppProcessInfo`, e.g. in a function `main()`:

```
// File main.mm
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#include "UseProcessInfoInC.hpp"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        MyCppProcessInfo pi;
        pi.printVersion();

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll try this soon. What's the reason for char version[] being `static`? is this to service then the method returns? Is there any way for getProcessInfoVersion_C to return a value instead of a pointer? Does for example C++ std::string work in .mm?

Comment: Your're welcome. There is no specific reason for using `char *` and `static`, and you can use any C++ code and datatype, e.g. `std::string`, in `.mm`. I adapted the code to use `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks again for the great answer. I sucessfully implemented it. While doing that I found that you need a runtime availability check when the code runs on OS X 10.9 or below. I added this check to the answer and hope you don't mind. I hope I did not mess up the code because my objective-c foo is very poor. Let me know if there is an issue in the part I changed.